# NServiceBus 6: want some errors to ignore eror queue

Tags: nservicebus

As per [Customizing Error Handling](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/pipeline/customizing-error-handling) "Throwing the exception in the catch block will forward the message to the error queue. If that's not desired, remove the throw from the catch block to indicate that the message has been successfully processed." That's not true for me even if I simply swallow any kind of exception in a behavior:

```
public override async Task Invoke(IInvokeHandlerContext context, Func<Task> next)
{
    try
    {
        await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint there and made sure execution hit the catch block. Nevertheless after intimidate and delayed retries messages inevitably ends up in error queue. And I have no more Behaviours in the pipeline besides this one.

Only if I run `context.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers();` inside the catch block it prevents sending error to the error queue, but it also prevents any further immediate and delayed retries.

Any idea on why it works in contravention of Particular NserviceBus documentation is very appreciated

NserviceBus ver. used: 6.4.3

**UPDATE**:

I want only certain type of exceptions not being sent to an error queue in NServiceBus 6, however to make test case more clear and narrow down the root cause of an issue I use just type Exception. After throwing exception, execution certainly hits the empty catch block. Here is more code to that:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
{
    public void Customize(EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration)
    {

     endpointConfiguration.DefineEndpointName("testEndpoint");
     endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<XmlSerializer>();
     endpointConfiguration.DisableFeature<AutoSubscribe>();
     configure
            .Conventions()
            .DefiningCommandsAs(t => t.IsMatched("Command"))
            .DefiningEventsAs(t => t.IsMatched("Event"))
            .DefiningMessagesAs(t => t.IsMatched("Message"));
     var transport = endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();


     var routing = transport.Routing();
     var rountingConfigurator = container.GetInstance<IRountingConfiguration>();
     rountingConfigurator.ApplyRountingConfig(routing);
     var instanceMappingFile = routing.InstanceMappingFile();
     instanceMappingFile.FilePath("routing.xml");

     transport.Transactions(TransportTransactionMode.TransactionScope);

     endpointConfiguration.Pipeline.Register(
                    new CustomFaultMechanismBehavior(),
                    "Behavior to add custom handling logic for certain type of exceptions");

     endpointConfiguration.UseContainer<StructureMapBuilder>(c => c.ExistingContainer(container));

     var recoverability = endpointConfiguration.Recoverability();

     recoverability.Immediate(immediate => 
                {
                    immediate.NumberOfRetries(2);
                });

     endpointConfiguration.LimitMessageProcessingConcurrencyTo(16);

     recoverability.Delayed(delayed =>
        {
                    delayed.NumberOfRetries(2);
        });

     endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("errorQueue");
    ...
    }
}

public class CustomFaultMechanismBehavior : Behavior<IInvokeHandlerContext>
{
    public override async Task Invoke(IInvokeHandlerContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        try
        {
            await next().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {               
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**
I think I know what's going on: message is handled by first handler that throws an exception which is caught by the Behavior catch block, but then NServiceBus runtime tries to instantiate second handler class which is also supposed to handle the message (it handles class the message is derived from). That's where another exception is thrown in a constructor of one of dependent class. StructureMap tries to instantiate the handler and all its dependent services declared in the constructor and in the process runs into the exception. And this exception is not caught by CustomFaultMechanismBehavior.

So my I rephrase my question now: **Is there any way to suppress errors (ignore error queue) occurring inside constructor or simply during StructureMap classes initialization?** Seems like the described way does not cover this kind of situations

Comment: Could you clarify what it is you are trying to achieve, from a functional perspective? Do you want to prevent _any_ message from arriving in the error queue, or only a certain type of messages? Are you perhaps able to create a repro of the issue and share it?

Comment: Could you share your behavior registration / base class code? Do you want to retries to still happen? but the message being ignored if all the retries were not successful? Could you elaborate what you want to achieve?

Comment: @DennisvanderStelt, I've updated the question. Yes, I want only certain exception not being sent to the error queue. Weather immediate and delayed retries are there or not for this type of exceptions is a less important thing. The main question is why they still get in the error queue

Comment: @YMC this is exactly how it is supposed to work. Your code - the amount the is posted and I can see - is identical to the error handling sample you can find below, Could you download that sample and see if that works for you? Which transport are you using? Could you post the complete endpoint configuration as well?

https://docs.particular.net/samples/message-error-handling/

Comment: Hi @HadiEskandari, I use msmq transport. Right, my code is identical to the one provided by the link. In the first place it was not, but then I gradually transferred it to the way provided in the documentation and it still does not work (still sending error to msmq error queue). I'm updating endpoint code adding more information. Thanks

Comment: I think I found what the problem is. Please read UPDATE 2 in the question description

Comment: @YMC see if my answer helps. I did reproduce it locally even without StructureMap. All you need is to have two handlers for the same message with one throwing an exception in the Handler and the other in the ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your behavior is activated on Handler invocation. This means you are catching exceptions happening inside the `Handle` method so any other exception, e.g. in the Constructor of the handler would not be caught.

To change the way you 'capture' the exceptions, you can change the way the behavior is activated, e.g. change it from `Behavior<IInvokeHandlerContext>` to `Behavior<ITransportReceiveContext>` which is activated when the transport receives a message. You can investigate on different stages and behaviors to see which one suits your purpose best.